# Docker Windows container: How to access domain port

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose

I'm developing a website using APS.NET in Visual Studio 2017.
I decided to use Docker to work around a bug in IIS from the last Windows update.

I need to access the website in the following url: http://seedweblocal:51414/

But it's not working, am I doing something wrong?

Here's my docker-compose.

```
version: '3'

services:
  seed.web:
    image: seed.web
    build:
      context: .\Seed.Web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: seedweb
    hostname: seedweblocal
    ports:
      - "51414:51414"
```

**Edited** by *Chun-Yen Wang* awnser.

I changed my Dockerfile to expose this port, but its don't work.

Continue only accessible in http://seedweblocal/

My Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
EXPOSE 51414
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides specifying host and container port mapping in docker-compose.yml, you need to EXPOSE port (51414) in the image seed.web as well. This should be done in its Dockerfile.